# Symmetrize a polynomial forgetting the commutativity property of multiplication

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I need a script to authomatically symmetrize a given polynomial. 
For example, if the input is

```
xy
```

the output should be

```
(xy+yx)/2
```

The same principle should work also for higher order polynomial. For example, if the input is

```
 xyz
```

the output should be

```
(xyz+xzy+yxz+yzx+zxy+zyx)/6
```

The input is, in general, a polynomial. If the input is

```
xy+wz
```

the output should be

(xy+yx+wz+zw)/2

It may happen that some terms come with some powers. If the input is

```
x^2 z
```

the output should be either

```
(xxz + xxz +xzx+ xzx + zxx + zxx)/6
```

or

```
(2x^2z+2xzx+2zx^2)/6
```

Both these ouputs are good.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you always dealing with monomials, or should a solution expect things like `x y + w z`?

Comment: The input could be a polynomial as well. For example, if the input is $xy+wz$, the output should be $(xy+yx+wz+zw)/2$, but I know a priori what are the variables that come into play. Moreover, of course, it may appen to have things like $x^2y$ as input. In this case, the output should be either $(xxz+xzx+xxz+xzx+zxx+zxx)/6$ or $(2x^2z + 2xzx+ 2zx^2)/6$. Both outputs are ok for me.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less, I've edited the question in order to meke my question more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
f[NonCommutativeMultiply[x__]] := Mean[Permutations[NonCommutativeMultiply[x]]]

f[x ** y ** z]
```

> 1/6 (x ** y ** z + x ** z ** y + y ** x ** z + y ** z ** x + 
>      z ** x ** y + z ** y ** x)

Adding

```
f[x_Times] := f /@ x
f[x_Plus] := f /@ x
f[x_?NumericQ] := x
```

allows us to treat also polynomials:

```
f[3 x ** x ** y + y ** y ** y + 54 x ** z ** y]
```

> x ** x ** y + x ** y ** x + y ** x ** x + y ** y ** y + 
>    9 (x ** y ** z + x ** z ** y + y ** x ** z + y ** z ** x + 
>       z ** x ** y + z ** y ** x)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can it handle a generic polynomial $P(x,y,z)$ such as $P(x,y,z)=3x^2y+y^3+54xzy$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. You gave me a huge help. Just a curiosity more. In the input the non-commutative multiplication $**$ is already made explicit. Is there a way to authomatically turn a traditional multiplication (such as $x*y$) into a non-commutative one, (such as $x**y$)?

Comment: Yes, you can always tuse replacement rules, e.g. `x x y //. {Power[a_, k_Integer?Positive] :> 
   NonCommutativeMultiply @@ ConstantArray[a, k], 
  Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply}` (however this won't work out with the coefficients).